# jquery plugin codaslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, coda-slider

I am trying to use codaslider plugin and it does not work for me. I think I am doing everyhtings right but still its not working. Can someone help me finding out what am I making mistake. Here is my code below. The problem is it does not slide from one panel to antoher. I already went through the documentation but I do not know what is the mistake i am making here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
       $('#codaslider5').codaSlider({
           dynamicArrows: false,
           dynamicTabs: false
       });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        #nav { width: 500px; background: blue; height: 50px; }
        ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; }
        #mainWrapper #nav ul li { float: left; margin-right: 40px; }
        #slider { width: 500px; background: red; overflow: hidden; }
        .codaslider { width: 1500px; background: greenyellow; }
        .panel { width: 500px; height: 100px; float: left; }
        .panel1 { background: green; }
        .panel2 { background: lightblue; }
        .panel3 { background: yellow; }
    </style>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="tab1"><a href="#1">Panel 1</a></li>
                <li class="tab2"><a href="#2">Panel 2</a></li>
                <li class="tab3"><a href="#3">Panel 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="codaslider" id="codaslider5">
                <div class="panel panel1">
                    <h2>Panel 1</h2>
                    <p>This is panel 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel2">
                    <h2>Panel 2</h2>
                    <p>This is panel 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel3">
                    <h2>Panel 3</h2>
                    <p>This is panel 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're missing `document` in `$().ready(function()`. Also you should typically place the code after the styles.

Comment: I added the document and put the code after styles but still not working.

Comment: Do you have Firebug or a suitable DOM inspector? Can you check if the path to the scripts is working correctly?

Comment: yes i checked it with firebug it is working

Comment: Also, there's a CSS file which needs to be added - `demo-menu.css`. Can you make the changes you've made to the code above to make it easier for others to debug as well?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I must have been messing around with this for the past hour or so, wondering why it didn't work because like you because it all looked like it should be fine.

I think I found the solution. It seems to be that codaSlider is picky about the names you give to your slider objects - they must contain dashes and must be in sequential order.

Your slider is named '#codaslider5', you need to change this to '#coda-slider-1' (if you use 2, 3...n it doesn't work - presumably it expects you to actually have sliders 1, 2, 3, 4 if you want to use an ID of 5).

Here we go:

Change:

```
$('#codaslider5').codaSlider({
```

to

```
$('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
```

Next, change:

```
<div id="nav">
```

to

```
<div id="coda-nav-1">
```

Next, change:

```
<div class="codaslider" id="codaslider5">
```

to

```
<div class="coda-slider" id="coda-slider-1">
```

Or for lazyness [here is the fixed file](http://pastebin.com/Ki7CSqPk), and the [diff](http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=Ki7CSqPk).

This will mess with your CSS so you'll have to fix it. But hopefully this gets you back on track.